# Import the C-extenison foo.so from another directory

Tags: python, python-import

I have the file foo.so, which is compiled from a C extension of Python. The file is located in the relative directory 'Dir'. How can I load the .so **without actually changing sys.path**?

I tried

```
from Dir import foo
```

and

```
import Dir.foo
```

Neither works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>add Dir to your module search path `sys.append('Dir')` and `import foo`</strike>

try to make Dir a python module by creating `__init__.py` in Dir file.

`__init__.py` should be like:

```
from foo import *
```

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the question, I need to avoid changing sys.path here.